# Overwrite a Spark DataFrame into location

Tags: r, sparklyr

I want to save my Spark DataFrame into directory using `spark_write_*` function like this:

```
spark_write_csv(df, "file:///home/me/dir/")
```

but if the directory is already there I will get error:

```
ERROR: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: path file:/home/me/dir/ already exists.;
```

When I'm working on the same data, I want to overwrite this dir - how can I achieve this? In documentation there is one parameter:

```
mode  Specifies the behavior when data or table already exists.
```

but it doesn't say what value you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `mode` should simply have value `"overwrite"`:

```
spark_write_csv(df, "file:///home/me/dir/", mode = "overwrite")
```